# sections of the iOS app become black in some devices

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app which is currently published, this one person reported a problem with an iPhone 7 iOS 13.5.1 where he could not use it, basically the background of a table view cell is completely black where on all other devices is white, because of that and since the text is black, this person can't read anything. Also in the search field he can't see what is being typed, there, the background is white and the text which is supposed to be black is white. We actually got a screenshot which is by the way not very clear but you can see a faded version of the text in both the search field and the table view.

We also have the same model and with the same OS version installed but are not seeing the issue, for now we have only gotten  report from this one person.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue that can point me to what the problem maybe?

[image]

Comment: Could be a dark mode vs. light mode issue?

Comment: @Gereon, thank you. The issue presents in dark mode. Please post as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to be an issue where your user has dark mode enabled, but your app appears to use a mixture of hardcoded and semantic colors.

As a quick workaround your can force your app to always use light mode by adding

```
<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
<string>Light</string>
```

to your `Info.plist`

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your background color to white instead default.
"default" will set your background color in black if the device is in dark mode.

Comment: This. Your keyboard looks as if it's the darkmode keyboard.